# JQuery Chaining Deferreds without callback pyramids

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-deferred

Is there a way to chain JQuery Deferreds to execute one after another without callback pyramids?

Right now I have to do something like this:

```
$.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log('Foo'); 
        dfd.resolve(); 
    }, 1000);
})
.done(function() {
    $.Deferred(function(dfd) { 
        console.log('Bar');
        dfd.resolve();
    }).done(function() { 
         console.log('done');
    });
});
```

Output: Foo, Bar, done

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log('Foo'); 
        dfd.resolve(); 
    }, 1000);
})
.then($.Deferred(function(dfd) { 
    console.log('Bar');
    dfd.resolve();
}))
.done(function() { console.log('done') });
```

Undesired Output: Bar, Foo, done

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is you are passing `.then()` a jQuery object whereas it expects a `function`. This code executes foo-bar-done as required.

```
$.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log('Foo'); 
        dfd.resolve(); 
    }, 1000);
}).then(function(){ 
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) { 
         console.log('Bar');
         dfd.resolve();
     });
}).done(function() { console.log('done') });
```

Comment: Note: This only works in JQuery 1.8+. Prior to that, you need to use `.pipe()`.

Comment: And prior to 1.6/1.7, `.pipe()` wouldn't work. Unless specified, I assume jQuery questions refer to the latest version, in which case this answer is correct and should be marked as such.

Comment: Sorry, I had unmarked it because upon further testing I had found it wasn't working. The 1st reason was the JQuery version, but the 2nd reason was the missing `return` keyword, which I've since corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Something like this should work:

```
var d1 = $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log('Foo'); 
        dfd.resolve(); 
    }, 1000);
});

var d2 = $.Deferred(function(dfd) { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
      console.log('Bar');
      dfd.resolve();
    }, 2000);
});

$.when(d1, d2).then(function() {console.log('done')});
```